# Change File Template for existing classes

Tags: file, intellij-idea, intellij-15

Each new created class applies file template rules, which by default is :

> /**
>    * Created by ${USER} on ${DATE}.
>    */

Speaking of my project, i have dozens of classes that has this template by default, and when it comes to code cleanup, it's really frustrating. Is it possible to replace file template in already EXISTING classes so replacement wouldn't take too much time (i was thinking to do  this manually, but i hope there's better solution for that)?

Thank you

Comment: I do not know how to do it with IntelliJ but you can do it with Sublime Text I believe.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an option for me atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to replace file template in already EXISTING classes ... ?

No, it's not possible. But IntelliJ has very powerful "Search and Replace" and refactoring capabilities.

[image]